# In WordPress, how can I display custom fields into a table based on category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Toolset plugin for custom post type and taxonomies. I:

1. Created "Jobs" custom post type.
2. Under jobs custom post type created custom post fields like,

   - Name of Board
   - Name of post
   - number of post
   - qualification
   - last date
   - more details
3. registered these fields under jobs custom post type.
4. created States as a custom taxonomy
5. under states created states of India

My aim is to display taxonomy wise --> "Jobs" custom post type - Post fields into a table in a custom page or archive template.

Comment: can you check for more understanding https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: add the code you have tried?

Comment: I've edited your post mostly for formatting and a little bit for grammar.   I used the list features of markdown to make the steps that you have already completed much clearer.   I also added "WordPress" to the title so that it is immediately clear what the context of this question is.

Comment: This question should probably be migrated to [the StackExchange WordPress development site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)